Create structure of eloquent models
I have a design problem.
I have three models:
class Restaurant extends Model
{
    public function discounts(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Discount::class)->withPivot('info');
    }
}

class Discount extends Model
{
    public function restaurants(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Restaurant::class);
    }

    public function birthday()
    {
        //???
    }
}

/** Or extends Model maybe? */
class Birthday extends Discount
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'kitchen',
        'alcohol',
        'alcohol_percent',
        // and many more fields that are specific only to the Birthday discount
    ];
}

A restaurant can have many discounts, and discounts can belong to many restaurants. The entire list of discounts has a common field info, which is contained in an pivot-table. Everything is simple here.
But there is a single discount called Birthday, for which there are many fields that are specific only to this discount. Therefore, I would like to store them in a separate Birthday model.
How can I correctly design the relationship structure?
I really don't want to store all the birthday discount fields in the pivot table as json. Because then this single field will mostly be empty.
Help me please :)

Have you considered Polymorphic Relationships? I'm not a fan of them because setting up foreign keys/constraints for them sucks, but the way you are doing things makes me wonder if it would be useful in your scenario. I imagine you could have other types of discounts depending on the promotion.

How i can use polymorphic relations in my case?

Discounts other than birthday cannot have other 100% fields.


Have you considered Polymorphic Relationships? I'm not a fan of them because setting up foreign keys/constraints for them sucks, but the way you are doing things makes me wonder if it would be useful in your scenario. I imagine you could have other types of discounts depending on the promotion. - My earlier comment

Here is an example using Polymorphic Relationships, mostly copied from the docs and adapted to your code above:
DB schema
birthday
    id - integer
    kitchen
    alcohol
    alcohol_percent
    // and many more fields that are specific only to the Birthday discount
 
discounts
    id - integer
    discountable_id - integer
    discountable_type - string
    info // discount info required for all discounts

Model code
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;
 
class Discount extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the parent commentable model (post or video).
     */
    public function discountable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;
 
class Restaurant extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the post's comments.
     */
    public function discounts(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Discount::class, 'discountable');
    }
}
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;
 
class Birthday extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the video's comments.
     */
    public function discounts(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Discount::class, 'discountable');
    }
}

Usage
$discount = Discount::find(1);
if ($discount->discountable instanceof Birthday) {
    dd($discount->discountable->alcohol_percent);
}
dd('Not a birthday discount');


Thanks, interesting solution, but i done this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/help-create-structure-of-eloquent-models

Yeah, JSON is an option too. You lose some data integrity because the JSON structure isn't enforced. There are trade-offs to any approach really and you know your application best.
